# How to you split a string into 10 letters each in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, split

This is my string:

```
data = abdskjfdskjfjkdseiruiskdfdsdfjsdjkfdsdfsdjk
```

I want to split my data into 10s

So, I want my output to look like:

```
abdskjfdsk
jfjkdseiru
```

and so on for the rest of the string.

I tried:

```
chunks, chunk_size = len(data), len(data)//10
[ data[i:i+chunk_size] for i in range(0, chunks, chunk_size) ]
```

but it didn't change anything and my output was

```
data = abdskjfdskjfjkdseiruiskdfdsdfjsdjkfdsdfsdjk
```

EDIT: 
This solved the issue:

```
import re
re.findall('.{10}', data)
```

Thank you !!

Comment: What happens if you execute x = [data[ ......] ; print(x) ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall)

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('.{10}', data)
['abdskjfdsk', 'jfjkdseiru', 'iskdfdsdfj', 'sdjkfdsdfs']
```

`.` matches any character (except for line terminators)

`{10}` Quantifier — Matches exactly 10 times

Answer (score 1):

when you have a string, you can subset by each of the elements of the string using brackets []. This is, if you want the first three elements fo your list you can use:

```
data[0:3]
```

next, we'll harness a list comprehension technique to do this process multiple times:

```
[data[character:character+10] for character in range(0, len(data),10)]
```

Comment: Some explanation would be nice.